# Get list of supported languages for Google SpeechRecognizer (GoogleTTSRecognitionService) on Android 13

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Before android 13 I can successfully get supported languages through broadcast receiver using intent RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS. On android 13 extras are empty. Code follows:

```
public class LanguageDetailsChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
        // for API < 13;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {
            Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
            if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE))  {
                //languagePreference = results.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);
            }
            if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
                //supportedLanguages =  results.getStringArrayList( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
            }
        }
    }
```

Surely I see new API for Android 13:

```
speechRecognizer.checkRecognitionSupport(testIntent, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), new RecognitionSupportCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSupportResult(@NonNull RecognitionSupport recognitionSupport) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " onError >>>>>>>>>>>> ?? " + error);
                    }
                });
```

which always drops me into onError with code 14.

BTW the same API works perfectly for Samsung speech recognizer (AiAiSpeechRecognitionService) which I am testing along with the Google service.

I have read [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#speech-service) which states that SpeechService was removed, but at the meantime they have introduced app to replace the service and furthermore, they have introduced new API (`checkRecognitionSupport`) which seems to produce error constantly.

And I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295030/query-supported-languages-with-google-speech-services-doesnt-work-on-android-13) which does not give me a hint of how to make work new API.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am seeing the error 14 and the empty Bundle as well. I do not see any solution to query the available languages. Did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting error 14 on the new checkRecognitionSupport API however I was able to get it to work for an on device recognizer. Here's a code sample.

```kotlin
if ( SpeechRecognizer.isOnDeviceRecognitionAvailable(context)) {
    var recognizer = createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer(context)
    var recognizerIntent =     
        Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    recognizer?.checkRecognitionSupport(recognizerIntent,         
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
        object : RecognitionSupportCallback {
            override fun onSupportResult(recognitionSupport: RecognitionSupport) {
                // use recognitionSupport.supportedOnDeviceLanguages 
                // or any of the other properties of recognitionSupport
            }
            override fun onError(error: Int) {
                // handle error conditions
            }
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat as you, seems like you have to use brute dict of

> Blockquote
> EXTRA_LANGUAGE
> Added in API level 3

```
public static final String EXTRA_LANGUAGE
```

Optional `IETF` language tag (as defined by BCP 47), for example `"en-US"`. This tag informs the recognizer to perform speech recognition in a language different than the one set in the `Locale.getDefault()`.

```
Constant Value: "android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE"
```

If you get any other ways please you are welcome.